# Proof that a subset of R has same cardinality as R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am sitting with a task where I have to prove the following:

Claim:
Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$, that contains an interval $I$ with $a < b$, has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.

So I think that I should prove that there exist a bijection from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$? I'm kinda lost, and don't know how to start.

There is a lemma 3 in the book saying:
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $-\infty\neq  a < b \neq \infty$. There exist a $f\colon ]-1; 1[ \to ]a; b[$ that is bijektiv. The intervals $]-1; 1[$ and $]a; b[$ has same cardinality.

Another lemma 4 says:
$f\colon ]0; 1[ \to ]1; \infty[$, $x\to \frac{1}{x}$, is bijective. The intervals $f\colon ]0; 1[ \to ]1; \infty[$ have same cardinality.

(There is an image added to lemma4)

[image]

The above interval $]-1; 1[$ has same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, and the $f$ is bijective
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Let $A$ be a subset that contains a non-trivial interval $I$. Then $\Bbb R=_c I\leq _c A\leq _c\Bbb R$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that cardinalities are ordered? That is, do you know that if a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a cardinality "not less than" $|\mathbb{R}|$ then it has cardinality equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$?

Comment: Hi. Yes I think I am. Isn't that what the Bernsteins-Schröders sentence says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

First prove that any two non-empty open intervals have the same cardinality.

Second, pass now to use the nice interval $\;(-\pi/2\,,\,\pi/2)\;$ and a rather nice, simple trigonometric function to show equipotency with $\;\Bbb R\;$

Comment: There is also a simple rational function that maps $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ bijectively.

Comment: Thanks for the replies people. I am really not good at proofs in maths. That's why I have paid for the course that I am following, so that I can learn more. The posts you have provided so far, doesn't help me more than the lemmas provided, which I can't use to my advantage. Please don't understand this in a negative way, I just don't know how else to say it. So can anyone be a little more specific, or maybe with examples? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a bijection from $I$ to $\mathbb R$ chose
$$f: (a,b) \to (-1,1), \qquad x\mapsto 2\frac{x-a}{b-a} - 1$$
which is (obviously) bijective. Then
$$g: (-1,1) \to \mathbb R, \qquad \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} - 1&x\in(0,1)\\0&x=0\\\frac{1}{x} + 1&x\in(-1,0)\end{cases}$$
(Taken from Lemma 4)
$$h := g\circ f : (a,b) \to\mathbb R$$
is bijective as a composition of bijective maps.

Comment: At this part: f:(a,b)→(−1,1),x↦x−ab−a−1. How did you get to -1 at: x↦x−ab−a−1?


Also... What is the conclusion on this: h:=g∘f:(a,b)→R? Why do you do that part?

Comment: Please use MathJax, your text is very hard to read ($\$\text{\frac\{a\}\{b\}}\$$ = $\frac a b$)
Second, $f(a) = -1, f(b) = 1$ - since $f$ is linear we know by mean-value theorem $f((a,b)) = (-1,1)$. The $h$ is _one_ bijection from $(a,b)$ onto $\mathbb R$

Comment: I see that you edited the f function and added the number 2 suddenly? And thank you very much for the help and comments. I am thinking. There should be a comment on the interval (a, b), according to Bernsteins-Schröders sentence? won't it clarify the argument why f is bijective? I know that you can just test it with values, but still, for a more formal argument and proof?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how you got to that formular of the function f. If it is not too much to ask, I'd be really grateful if you could tell me

Comment: It's a solution of a simple linear equation:
Find $f(x) = ax + b$ s.t. $f(x_0) = y_0, f(x_1) = y_1$.
Using the constraints $$f(a) = -1, f(b) = 1$$
you get the desired result. The inverse of $f$ can be found by the same method and
$$f^{-1}(-1) = a, f^{-1}(1) = b$$

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves the problem for you, please mark it as solved; if not, please ask away.

Comment: To prove lemma 3, one could argue that we have a function that is continous, and has the right endpoints, så it gets surjective, and it is injective since it is strictly increasing.

How can I argue that lemma 4 above is bijective? I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No one has pointed out yet that to prove the statement of the OP (where a subset *contains* an interval), you're also going to need to invoke the theorem that bears the names Cantor, Schroeder, and Bernstein (in some order or other).

The idea is to construct an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ into the subset $S$ by injecting it into an interval $(a, b)$ inside $S$ (the other answers describe how to do this), and of course we have an injection from $S$ into $\mathbb{R}$ given by subset inclusion. Then apply the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, which says that if there is an injective function $f: A \to B$ and an injective function $g: B \to A$, then there exists a bijection $\phi: A \to B$.